# python web scraping .find() returns nothing

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new in python, was following a few video tutorials to do some data scraping from a listing site.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listing-info">
  <h3>
    <a href="/property-listing/english-townhouse-residence" itemprop="url" title = "For Sale English Townhouse"><span itemprop="name">English Townhouse</span>
    </a>
  </h3>
  <ul class="listing-features">
    <li class="lst-details">
      <span class="lst-ptype">Semi-Detached House </span>
      <span class="lst-tenure">Freehold</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Under element ul - listing feature, I would like to consume 'Semi-detached house' as residential type and 'Freehold' as residential tenure.

I have the above html parsed into **listing-info** variable.

My code trial:

```
listing-info.li.text
```

Here I'm able to get **Semi-detached house**

Understanding that there are two span classes in list and so to be specific I tried:

```
listing-info.find('span',class_='1st-ptype')
listing-info.find('span',class_='1st-tenure')
```

Both returnes empty.
Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you misread the class name "**l**st-ptype" and typed "**1**st-ptype" instead.

Comment: OKAY THIS IS EMBARRASING hahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can search directly for the housing types:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<div class="listing-info">
  <h3>
    <a href="/property-listing/english-townhouse-residence" itemprop="url" title = "For Sale English Townhouse"><span itemprop="name">English Townhouse</span>
     </a>
  </h3>
  <ul class="listing-features">
    <li class="lst-details">
      <span class="lst-ptype">Semi-Detached House </span>
      <span class="lst-tenure">Freehold</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
"""
s = soup(s, 'lxml')
housing_types = [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':re.compile('lst-ptype|lst-tenure')})]
```

Output:

```
[u'Semi-Detached House ', u'Freehold']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification to @Ajax Code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<div class="listing-info">
<h3>
<a href="/property-listing/english-townhouse-residence" itemprop="url" title = "For Sale English Townhouse"><span itemprop="name">English Townhouse</span>
</a>
</h3>
<ul class="listing-features">
<li class="lst-details">
   <span class="lst-ptype">Semi-Detached House </span>
   <span class="lst-tenure">Freehold</span>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
"""
s = soup(s, 'lxml')
housing_types = [i.text for i in s.find_all('span', {'class':re.compile('lst-[a-z]*')})]
print(housing_types)
['Semi-Detached House ', 'Freehold']
```